# ¿Cómo evitar que se cambie la fuente al agregar un icono?

Tags: javascript, css

estoy creando una tabla dinámicamente utilizando javascript, y en uno de los td de cada tr estoy creando un botón, mi problema es que al momento de agregarle el icono, cambia la fuente del botón, viéndose un tanto extraño, como puedo evitar esto? Estoy utilizando fontawesome

```
body = document.getElementById("tags_tbdy");
tr = document.createElement("tr");

button = document.createElement('button'); 
button.type= 'button';
button.id = 'button_' + i;

body.appendChild(tr);
td = document.createElement("td");
button.setAttribute('data-id_tag',tags[i]['id']);
td.appendChild(button);
button.className='btn btn-primary';
button.classList.add("fas", "fa-edit");
button.innerHTML=' Editar';
tr.appendChild(td);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Debes de crear una nueva etiqueta para el icono, un `span` o un `i` y colocal el icono en él, y el texto en el button. espero se haya entendido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema que tuviste fue que no agregas la etiqueta (i) dentro del boton ya que es la etiqueta que se utiliza para los iconos.

Me centre en el botón así que esa es la solución, pero en la parte de javascript hay dos lineas que están comentadas puedes utilizar cualquiera de las dos para insertar el texto al botón, pero el texto quedara a la izquierda, así que utilice CSS para poner el texto a la derecha, las lineas están comentadas si quieres alinearlo de manera diferente eso queda en tus manos.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <style>
        .btn {
            color: red;
            font-family: "Lucida Console", Courier, monospace;
        }
        .btn:after {
            content: " Editar ";
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="demo">

  <div>
<script>
var demo = document.querySelector("#demo");

button = document.createElement('button'); 
demo.appendChild(button);
button.className='btn';
//button.innerHTML="Editar ";
//button.textContent='Editar ';

var etiqueta = document.querySelector("button");

i = document.createElement('i');
etiqueta.appendChild(i);
i.className='fas fa-air-freshener';
<script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Agradezco su respuesta, sin embargo no me funciono(no probé lo de css). Pero me ayudo a encontrar una solución, la dejare en un comentario. Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Si bien la respuesta de @Neury no me funciono del todo, me ayudo a encontrar una solución, así que la marque como correcta, dejare mi código completo.

```
  body = document.getElementById("tags_tbdy");


for (var i in tags) {

tr = document.createElement("tr");

body.appendChild(tr);
td = document.createElement("td"); 
td.innerHTML = tags[i]['title'];
tr.appendChild(td);

body.appendChild(tr);
td = document.createElement("td"); 
td.innerHTML = tags[i]['url_clean'];
tr.appendChild(td);

body.appendChild(tr);
td = document.createElement("td"); 
td.innerHTML = tags[i]['created_at'];
tr.appendChild(td);

//boton
button = document.createElement('button'); 
button.type= 'button';
button.id = 'button_' + i;


body.appendChild(tr);
td = document.createElement("td");
button.setAttribute('data-id_tag',tags[i]['id']);
td.appendChild(button);
button.className='btn btn-primary';
button.innerHTML='<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>'+' Editar';
tr.appendChild(td);


}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]